# How to map objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a complex object, such as:

```
var age = {3: {id:1, name: John}, 4: {id:8, name:Johny}};
```

I have another object:

```
var student = {3:1, 4:1};
```

What I want to do is insert the age object into the object keys of the student object.

I want the result as:

```
{1: {3: {id:1, name: nose}}, 8: {4: {id:8, name:hands}}}
```

I'm not going anywhere with my trying to posting it here.

Comment: Do you mean `{3: {1: {id:1, name: nose}}, 4: {2: {id:2, name:hands}}}`? The object you want isn't written correctly (there's two missing close brackets) and I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why are you asking of something so simple or why have you named `age` an object that contains ids and bodyparts. Consider redesigning your code. Anyway, a simple loop gets the job done:

```
   for (var key in student) {
       var ageIndex = student[key]
       student[key] = {}
       student[key][ageIndex] = age[ageIndex]
   }
```

Comment: this doesnt work, ageIndex is not set as object key, instead it is taken as is i,e string.
Result:
  {3: {ageIndex: {id:1, name: nose}}, 4: {ageIndex: {id:2, name:hands}}}